# Why do Linux distros use both the grub and syslinux bootloaders?

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, isolinux

Whenever I open a Linux distro iso file there is always a grub and an isolinux bootloader, I realized they use isolinux to boot the installation.

Can't we use grub for that? is isolinux faster and better for installation?

Comment: [There's some history for Ubuntu specifically over on AskUbuntu that may be helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651902/what-is-the-difference-between-grub-and-syslinux), but I think this is a good "general" question. ISOLINUX is very common.

Comment: In general, distros offer what is available. I don't think there's a specific "why" behind that. And I still use lilo for some of my older systems... just because they never made the switch.